# GET request in Angular JS by passing user selected value from HTML in URL parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to do a GET request and change the endpoint URL parameter based on the selected value in Angular JS (Version :- Angular 1). I have a few API endpoints, which accepts GET requests and returns JSON. JSON structure is the same and values are different only for different selected options. We can change the URL end parameter to call that particular API. As an example,

Endpoint is `api.endpoint.com/{{options}}/`

JSON structure is

```
[
  {
    id : "1",
    value : "value1"
  }
]
```

Whenever we select an option, it will replace the `{{option}}` with that selected value. Suppose, if we select `option 2` then it will instantly hit the `api.endpoint.com/option2/` and show the output in the below `<p>` tag. `<p>` tag should be updated automatically based on the option selection without reloading the whole page.

This is the Angular controller code that I am trying. What is the recommended way to call my API when the select option changes ?

Angular:

```
app.controller('optionController', ['$scope','$http', '$window', 'Selectoption', function($scope, $http, $window, Selectoption) {
  $scope.selectoptions = [];
  Selectoption.query({},function(data) {
    $scope.selectoptions = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="option_name">
  <option>Select Options</option>
  <option>My Options</option>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
</select>
<div class = "para" ng-repeat = "option in options">
  <p>{{option.id}}</p>
  <p>{{option.value}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend making your question more explicit. Instead of saying you're new to Angular and don't know where to call the API, ask a specific question like "What is the recommended way to call my API when the select option changes?"

Comment: Look at [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood from your problem statement is that you want to do an API call with selected drop down values and changing the API URL dynamically.

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EvQvZT?p=preview) for the same.

I have changed your controller a bit to pass the selected value to the URL on the drop down selection.The current code won't work as it has no proper API URL but if you can do the same changes it will work for you.

And also add `ng-change` in your `<select>` tags to trigger the API call on a change in selection.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="OptionController ">

  <select ng-model="option_name" ng-change="selectedOption(option_name)">
    <option>Select Options</option>
    <option>My Options</option>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
  </select>
  <div class="para" ng-repeat="option in options">
    <p>{{option.id}}</p>
    <p>{{option.value}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller('OptionController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', 'Selectoption', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, Selectoption) {

  $scope.selectoptions = [];

  $scope.selectedOption = function(option) {
    Selectoption.query(option).then(function(response) {
      console.log("testing response: " + response);


        $scope.selectoptions = response.data;
        console.log(data);

    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log("could not lget data due to error...");
    });
  };


}]);

app.service('Selectoption', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {

  return {
    query: function(option) {
      return $http.get("http://validUrl/test/" + option, {

      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: One doubt is, I also want to show the response in the <p> tag whenever we hit the API. Do I need to add anything here <div class="para" ng-repeat="option in options"> to bring options ?

Comment: Nothing to add just populate the Options object when you receive data from API call . In this case it's $scope.selectoptions

Comment: if (response.content === "Success") {
        $scope.selectoptions = response.data;
       options = $scope.selectoptions ;
        console.log(data);
      }
Like this ?

Comment: Make it $scope.options = response.data

Comment: It is not working. So, I have this JSON, https://api.myjson.com/bins/gdpu7/ source. Now, I am placing 'gdpu7' in one of the options, selecting it but the response is not showing. plunker :-
 https://plnkr.co/edit/hybGmBMKoU1ASf5GoInd?p=preview

Comment: Hi just removed the   if (response.content === "Success")  here is the updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/FHnJ8v5OPpav7pAWWtAD?p=preview  Please see the edited answer